# Android:how to get real dimension of a drawable in a imageview with fitxy scaletype?

Tags: android, dimension

I have an imageview with the fitxy scaletype.
I need to get the real dimension of its drawable but with the code below I get its dimension in fitxy mode.

```
     int finalHeight, finalWidth;
final ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.scaled_image);
final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.size_label);
ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        // Remove after the first run so it doesn't fire forever
        iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        finalHeight = iv.getMeasuredHeight();
        finalWidth = iv.getMeasuredWidth();
        tv.setText("Height: " + finalHeight + " Width: " + finalWidth);
        return true;
    }
});
```

how to get real dimension of a drawable in imageview with fitxy scaletype?

Answer (score 0):

Use either of the two methods to get the respective height and width

```
Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
// Approach 1
drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(); // drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(); //

//Approach 2   
Rect rect = drawable.getbounds();
rect.height();
rect.width();
```

But made sure you apply this code after ImageView onDraw, measure and layout pass to get proper width every single time.